# Room one-to-many, to many

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, one-to-many

I am little a bit confused on how i should set up a data class consisting of two lists.

I have a data class looking like this

```
@Entity(tableName = "recipe")
data class Recipe(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
val recipeName: String,
//val keyIngrediens: List<KeyIngredient>,
//val steps: List<steps>
```

So for `KeyIngrediens` i have set it up like this and it works perfectly without problems

```
@Entity
data class KeyIngredients(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
val title: String,
val image: String,
val undertitle: Int,
val recipeName: String
)

data class RecipeWithkeyIngredients(
@Embedded val recipe: Recipe,
@Relation(
    parentColumn = "recipeName",
    entityColumn = "recipeName"
)
val keyIngredients: List<KeyIngredients>
)
```

So basically, i got it to work with one list and one object, but Im a bit confused as how i should handle it when i have two lists in a single object. Right now I'm calling `RecipeWithKeyIngredients` which returns the recipe object with the list of key ingredients, but i don't know how to make it also contain the steps list.

In short it should be like `RecipeWithkeyIngredientsANDsteps` if that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is not enough for recipes. A recipe contains many ingredients, an ingredient belongs to many recipes. So it should be handled with many-to-many relationship.

```
@Entity
data class Recipe(
  @PrimaryKey
  val recipeId: Long,
  val name: String
)

@Entity
data class KeyIngredient(
  @PrimaryKey
  val keyIngredientId: Long,
  val title: String,
  val image: String,
  val undertitle: Int,
)

@Entity
data class Step(
  @PrimaryKey
  val stepId: Long,
  val instruction: String,
  val stepRecipeId: Long
)

@Entity(
  primaryKeys = ["recipeId", "keyIngredientId"]
)
data class RecipeKeyIngredient(     
  val recipeId: Long,
  val keyIngredientId: Long
)
```

Get the list of ingredients of a recipe

```
data class RecipeWithIngredients (
    @Embedded
    val recipe: Recipe,
    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "recipeId",
            entity = KeyIngredient::class,
            entityColumn = "ingredientId",
            associateBy = Junction(
                    value = RecipeKeyIngredient::class,
                    parentColumn = "recipeId",
                    entityColumn = "keyIngredientId"
            )
    )
    val keyIngredients: List<KeyIngredient>
)
```

Get the list of recipes with the same ingredient

```
data class IngredientWithRecipes(
  @Embedded
  val ingredient: Ingredient,
  @Relation(
        parentColumn = "ingredientId",
        entity = Recipe::class,
        entityColumn = "recipeId",
        associateBy = Junction(
                value = RecipeKeyIngredient::class,
                parentColumn = "ingredientId",
                entityColumn = "recipeId"
        )
  )
  val recipes: List<Recipe>
)
```

Now you can query database for the result as:

```
@Dao
interface RecipeKeyIngredientDao {
  @Query("SELECT * FROM Recipe")
  fun getRecipeWithIngredients(): LiveData<List<RecipeWithIngredients>>

  @Query("SELECT * FROM KeyIngredient")
  fun getIngredientWithRecipes(): LiveData<List<IngredientWithRecipes>>
}
```

For the other part of the question, a recipe typically contains specific set of steps (instructions?) and to define the relationship between recipe and steps you will need nested relationship which defines one-to-many relationship between recipe and steps, and get the recipe from already modelled `IngredientsOfRecipe` instead of Recipe table which will give recipe with ingredients. Model the same as

```
data class RecipeWithIngredientsAndSteps(
    @Embedded val recipe: IngredientsOfRecipe
    @Relation(
        entity = Step::class,
        parentColumn = "recipeId",
        entityColumn = "stepRecipeId"
    )
    val steps: List<Step>
)
```

Query using single transaction as follows

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM Recipe")
fun getRecipeWithIngredientsAndSteps(): List<RecipeWithIngredientsAndSteps>
```

Please refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#nested-relationships)

Comment: That's an optimal approach. 
Since he wants a recipe with a list of ingredients and a list of steps.

Lets assume all these steps map to the recipe and has a rank with it (for order)

( may be we can call it (many-to-many)-to-one )
what would be your ans?

Comment: This is probably the more right approach for my problem. But as Farees says, steps needs to be a list of steps, so i can design the UI as: step 1: Add water. Step 2: heat up water to 100 degress. Step 3: ... Step n. So then again, how do i go about many-to-many)-to-one. But thank you for your throughly contribution

Comment: Please check the edited answer, you will need nested relationship there. You may model one-to-many between recipe and steps first and then many-to-many between recipe and ingredients. In the answer, to add to the already modelled many-to-many between recipe and ingredients, I have added one-to-many between recipe and steps later.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Steps data class as follows:

```
@Entity
data class Steps(
    @PrimaryKay
    val stepName: String,
    val duration: Int,
    val recipeName: String,
    val rank: Int
)
```

```
data class RecipeWithKeyIngredientsAndSteps(
    @Embedded recipe: Recipe,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "recipeName",
        entityColumn = "recipeName"
    )
    val keyIngredients: List<KeyIngredients>,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "recipeName",
        entityColumn = "recipeName"
    )
    val steps: List<Steps>
)
```

At the end it's still a One-to-N Relationship

Comment: I think this answer would work if i give the ingredient list an iD so it is unique. Thank you!